# Who was Nehorai?

Tags: names, tannaim

Is anything known about the Tanna named Nehorai? He had a son R' Yosei (also a Tanna). There's also a R' Nehorai ben Shemayah (or Shema'yah? I'm not sure). Are they the same person? Is anything known about him (them)?

Comment: See Eruvin 13b.

Comment: @DoubleAA: but see also Shabbos 147b.

Comment: Some say Rabbi meir,Rabbi Nechemia,talmid of Rav Tarfon.

Comment: Or Rabbi Elazar ben Arach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Shabbas 147b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=147b&format=pdf) - Rabbi Nehorai is either Rabbi Nechemya or Rabbi Elazar Ben Aruch

[Eiruvin 13b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=3&daf=13b&format=pdf)  - Rabbi Meir's real name is Rabbi Nehorai(see however [Kiddushin 82](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=20&daf=82&format=pdf) where Rabbi Meir and Rabbi Nehorai are in the same mishna with different opinions) and the gemera then brings down the same gemara as in Shabbas 147b about Rabbi Nechemya and Rabbi Elazar ben Aruch being Rabbi Nehorai.

[Nazir 5a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=17&daf=5&format=pdf)     - Rabbi Nehorai says in the name of Rabbi Yehoshua different period then other rabbis mentioned as Rabbi Nehorai. Rabbi Nehorai and Rabbi Yossi argue in [Nazir 66](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=17&daf=66&format=pdf) (where did you see that his son was Rabbi Yossi)?

Never seen a Rabbi Nahorai ben Shemhya,where did you see this?

Comment: Sam, thanks for all the background! I Googled Nehorai and came up with an entry on Jewish Encyclopedia for [Jose b. Nehorai](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/8799-jose-b-nehorai).

Comment: @SethJ interesting it is a Yerushalmi in Berchas. i found this also Medrash Rabbah Parshas Va'yeshev 91:9 : ויאמר לא ירד בני עמכם וגו' 
רבי חנינא ורבי מרינוס, תרויהון אמרין בשם אבא נהוראי: בשעה שהיה אדם אומר דבר מתוקן לפני ר' טרפון, היה אומר: כפתור ופרח!